# How can I record my activities on screen using a Mac?

Tags: macos, screen-recorder

I am looking for a way to to record my actions on screen using a Mac.

I want to demonstrate an iPad application or demonstrate how to do a certain OSX task - like opening keynote or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Snow Leopard, Quicktime has screen recording built in.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for [iShowU](http://www.shinywhitebox.com/home/home.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the action is not too long which you want to demonstrate, you can use this the pixel egg "capture gif" app (http://www.pixelegg.me/capture-gif) to record your screen as an animated gif. You can also use: http://recordit.co/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.  Please take the tour at https://superuser.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.